# Join creates duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to join 3 tables in BigQuery that contain sales for products with the same identifier (SKU) and attending to the order date.

My goal would be to have in one table the order date, Sales Table 1, Sales Table 2, Sales Table 3 and Product identifier (SKU). For that I've been trying the next query:

```sql
SELECT
  Order_Date, Sales1, Sales2, Sales3, SKU
FROM
  Table 1
LEFT JOIN
  Table 2 ON Order_Date_Table1 = Order_Date_Table2 AND SKU_Table1 = SKU_Table2
LEFT JOIN
  Table 3 ON Order_Date_Table1 = Order_Date_Table3 AND SKU_Table1 = SKU_Table3
```

However when 2 of the tables contain sales for the same SKU and the same day, I get duplicated rows. Something similar happens with all other join types.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that aggregation can be a solution for your problem:

```
SELECT Order_Date, SKU, SUM(Sales1), SUM(Sales2), SUM(Sales3)
...
GROUP BY Order_Date, SKU
```

Comment: Hi Holger, lovely thanks for your answer. Unfortunately aggregation doesn't solve the problem because it just adds up the "duplicated rows".
My goal is to to have in one table three columns each with the sales amount of the different sources for that day and SKU, however with join the data only gets add up if the tables have sales for a specific day and SKU. Then is when duplication happens. If for a certain day or SKU there is not a value for other tables, then it "disappears". I hope I am able to express it clearly...